# Having one .cpp file communicate with a class.cpp and a class.h file

Tags: c++, file, class, compilation

I don't know the correct syntax for Dice.h and Dice.cpp to talk to my final game.cpp file.

I am getting a compile error that is returning a undefined reference to Dice::Dice()

Here are my 3 file headers

**Game.cpp**

```
#include "Dice.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{ int sum;
  Dice dice1;
  Dice dice2;
      dice1.roll();
      dice2.roll();
      sum = dice1.getFace() + dice2.getFace();
      cout << sum;

  return 0;

}
```

**Dice.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>


// definition of class Dice
class Dice //... cont
```

**Dice.cpp**

```
#include "Dice.h"
using namespace std;


Dice::Dice() //... cont
```

I get the error when i compile by typing g++ -Wall -o game game.cpp 
Is this the correct way to compile multiple files?

Answer (score 1):

Just because you have the includes in the files doesn't mean they will be compiled together.

Try g++ -Wall -o game Dice.cpp Game.cpp

...I could be slightly wrong on the command but that should work

Side note you should really look into Makefiles. Makes everything so much easier.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is close, but slightly off. Enter

```
++ -Wall -o game game.cpp Dice.cpp
```

Make sure that game is lower case, and I *think* the file containing `main()` needs to go first.